# Is Jetpack Compose Crossfade just a subset functionality of AnimateContent?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

From https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation, I learned about `AnimatedContent` which I can do a simple crossfade as below

```
fun MyFunction() {
    Column {
        var currentPage by remember { mutableStateOf("0") }
        AnimatedContent(targetState = currentPage,
            transitionSpec = {
                fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(150)) with
                        fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(150))
            }) { screen -> Text("Page $screen") }
        Button(onClick = {
            currentPage = (0..10).random().toString()
        }) {
            Text("Click Me")
        }
    }
}
```

However, later, I found there's a `Crossfade` function as well, and I can just use it.

```
fun MyFunction() {
    Column {
        var currentPage by remember { mutableStateOf("0") }
        Crossfade(targetState = currentPage) { screen ->
            Text("Page $screen")
        }
        Button(onClick = {
            currentPage = (0..10).random().toString()
        }) {
            Text("Click Me")
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like `Crossfade` is just probably a subset of what `AnimateContent` can do. Is that correct? If not, what `Crossfade` can do, that is not covered by `AnimateContent`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `Crossfade` does a subset of what `AnimatedContent` does.

`Crossfade` is a single-purpose, therefore easy-to-use animation API. We expect it to be a low friction entry point for most people to start with. Once you are familiar with the mental model of `Crossfade` , it is relatively straightforward to carry that over in `AnimatedContent` . Meanwhile, `AnimatedContent` also brings in the enter/exit transition vocabulary from `AnimatedVisibility` , we intended it to be a natural progression going from `AnimatedVisibility` to `AnimatedContent` as well.

The intention for this design is to offer easy-to-learn animation primitives that serve not only as the starting point for anyone new to Compose, but also as building blocks for the more powerful APIs that one can at some point progress into. :)